# Pipe not found Ionic 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'distance'
})
export class DistancePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(distance: number, ...args: any[]): string {
    return distance.toFixed(2) + "m";
  }

}
```

My pipe. I generated it with ionic g pipe pipes/distance

```
import { DistancePipe } from './pipes/distance.pipe';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DistancePipe],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Geolocation,
    ImagePicker ,
    FilePath
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My AppModule. It adds the Pipe automatically.

```
{{object.distance | distance}}
```

This is how I use it. on object.page.html

My error is:

core.js:4197 ERROR Error: The pipe 'distance' could not be found!

How can I solve it? Should it not work out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the pipe to the object.module.ts.

I add it as a declaration.